# How can I deinstall Drive Genius?

Tags: macos

I had installed a trial version of [Drive Genius](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/drive_genius.php). Now I want to delete it.

I go to Applications list, it is not there. I search its name in SpotLight, it is not there either. But it keeps attaching its self to the menu bar at the top.

How can I deinstall Drive Genius?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Drive Genius 3 User Guide](https://www.prosofteng.com/support/docs/Drive-Genius-3-User-Guide.pdf):

> To completely remove Drive Genius 3 and its utilities from your hard disk, click on Uninstall from the Drive Genius 3 menu. A prompt will appear to confirm you want to uninstall the application and will require administrator authentication to complete the process:
>
> - Uninstall: Drive Genius 3 will remove only its support files from the operating system, but will leave the application and registration in its folders for future references.
> - Uninstall All: Drive Genius 3 will remove all its files, including the support files, registration files and move the application to the trash can.

In case you've already deleted parts of the installation, you may need to re-download/install the [Demo version](https://www.prosofteng.com/drive-genius-mac-protection-software/) first ([direct download link](https://www.prosofteng.com/download/?dg5)).

Comment: Maybe it's better to contact their support directly then.

Comment: Drive Genius can install a background task (they call it Drive Pulse) and you probably still have that installed. Since you have already deleted the App (and it's uninstaller) from /Applications, you will need to either follow their manual removal process or re-install the demo version of the app and then perform the uninstall / removal of the optional system component. Be sure you remove Drive Pulse and then choose Uninstall All.

Answer (score 3):

In order to properly uninstall the demo of Drive Genius 3, you will need to manually uninstall it.

To manually uninstall Drive Genius 3 delete the following files and folders at the end of the paths listed below. Double click on your "Mac HD" drive to start the path.

`/Library/Application Support/DriveGenius` (folder)
`/Applications/Drive Genius 3.app` (icon)

If you are running OS X Lion, Mountain Lion, or Mavericks the last three files/folders are located in the user's `Library` folder which is hidden by the operating system. You can temporarily access this folder by opening a Finder window and pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This will bring up "Go to the folder", enter `~/Library` and click go.

`/Users/Library/Application Support/DriveGenius` (folder)  `/Users/Library/Preferences/com.prosofteng.DriveGenius2.plist` (file)
`/Users/Library/Preferences/com.prosofteng.DGAgent.plist` (file)

Now you will need to restart your computer.

<sup>You can contact Drive Genius support at (877)477-6763 [press 2 for support].</sup>

Comment: Also /Library/LaunchAgents/com.prosofteng.DGMonitor.plist

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to disable DrivePulse, but not get rid of the Drive Genius app (it's really a great app overall) then launch Drive Genius, select Preferences from the Drive Genius menu and then click on the button "Disable DrivePulse."

Then you can simply launch Drive Genius for basic maintenance and repair whenever you need it (some of the extended features are not available without DrivePulse running - but most of the Apps within the program run just fine).

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall DrivePulse, delete the following files, substituting "username" with your user name:

```
/Library/Application\ Support/DriveGenius/com.prosofteng.DGMonitor.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.prosofteng.DriveGenius.locum.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.prosofteng.DriveGenius.locum
/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.prosofteng.DGMonitor.plist
/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.prosofteng.DGAgent.plist
```

Then restart the mac.